# Create a network graph manually

Tags: python, user-interface, graph

I am looking to create a program in python that will allow me to draw a graph manually, that is to say, by placing the points (vertex) and clicking on two vertices in order to connect them and thus form an edge and above all I am looking to that this graph is not just a drawing because I have to extract the adjacency and incidence matrices from it and also apply algorithms on it (DFS, BFS, DJikstra).

I tried and searched everywhere but I can't, I can only create vertices and edges using the functions of the Networkx library (add_node and add_edge) which do not meet my needs because with these I can create a graph only by implementations.
Here is the interface of the program I am making, I want that when I click on the "Vertex" option a new window opens and I can place the vertices and then with the "Edge" option connect two peaks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbTCk.jpg)

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: This is way too broad a question. That said, you're not going to find something that does the entirety of what you're describing for you. What you need to do is learn to use a GUI library that will let you take mouse input and translate it to the screen, and then write your own logic to connect those mouse inputs to a graph library such as you describe.

Comment: They're asking for a python library, right, not just a standalone tool? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a decent GUI framework, then this sort of thing is easily accomplished.

As a first step, you need to implement the following

- Add node

  - move mouse cursor to location
  - click right mouse button
  - select "Add Node" menu item from pop-up
  - node will be displayed at mouse location as a black circle
- Select node

  - move mouse cursor over node
  - click left mouse button
  - selected node will be drawn in red
- Add link

  - select first node
  - move mouse cursor over second node
  - click right mouse button
  - select "link" menu item from pop-up
  - link will be drawn between nodes
- Move node

  - move mouse cursor over node
  - press and hold left mouse button
  - drag mouse while holing down left button.
  - ( the node  and connected links will follow the mouse curor )
  - release button at reuired new location

As an example of how this can be done, you may find it helpful to take a look at an implementation using C++ at https://github.com/JamesBremner/graphex2.  This uses the WINDEX gui framework - most gui frameworks offer the same methods, so it should be a straightforward task to port this line by line to python.